# How can I wipe my stolen iPhone with no sim

Tags: iphone

My iphone has been stolen, however I did not keep a sim in it since I no longer use it as a phone, just for a music player. It's password protected however in the notes app there's private and confidential information. Is there any way apple can wipe the whole device with just my apple ID?

Comment: Is the phone registered with Find my iPhone?

Comment: I'm not sure, can't remember. Already tried it but it said device is offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to wipe it is to use "Find my iPhone" (assuming it's registered there) and issue the "Wipe" command from there. As the iPhone doesn't have a SIM you'll have to wait until it gets online via WiFi.